# hadoop current leaseholder is trying to recreate file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

My MapReduce job processes data by dates and needs to write output to a certain folder structure. Current expectation is to generate out put in following structure:

days => days/months/file

**Reducer Class:**

```
public static class Reducerclass  extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> multipleOutputs;
        public void reduce(Text rkey, Iterable<Text> rvalue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
            for(Text value : rvalue) {              

                Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(value.toString()));     
                String datestring = dateFormat.format(date); 
                //              context.write(new Text(rkey + ", "),new Text(", "+value +", "+datestring));


                String[] parts = datestring.split(" ");
                String[] dateparts = parts[0].split("-");

                String day = dateparts[2]; 
                String month = dateparts[1]; 
                String year = dateparts[0]; 


                String baseFileName ="Days";  
                String dayFolderpath = baseFileName + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                String outputFileName = baseFileName + "/" + month + "/" + day; 
                if(datestring.equals("2017-10-26 20:30:42") || datestring.equals("2017-10-26 20:29:32")){

                    multipleOutputs.write(new Text(rkey + ", "), new Text(", "+value +", "+datestring),outputFileName) ;
                }
                else{   

                multipleOutputs.write(new Text(rkey + ", "), new Text(", "+value +", "+datestring),generateFileName(new Text(rkey),new Text(value) )) ;
                }

            }   
        }
        String generateFileName(Text key, Text value){
            return key.toString() + "_" + value.toString();     
        }

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context){
            multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void cleanup(final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            multipleOutputs.close();
        }
    }
```

When i ran the jar am getting following error message

```
17/11/14 18:30:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1510547616164_0054_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): failed to create file /user/hdfs/OutputFile/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1510547616164_0054_r_000000_0/Days/10/26-r-00000 for DFSClient_attempt_1510547616164_0054_r_000000_0_757297700_1 for client 10.0.2.15 because current leaseholder is trying to recreate file.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3171)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have missed is:

```
job.setReducerClass(ReducerFormatMultiOutput.class);
```

Please post the driver code to find the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

if your outputStream is close error，then next time you get append outputStream will occor error with: because current leaseholder is trying to recreate file. 
because the outputStream is not use any more，so if you close fail, you need to recover the lease by use recoverLease, code example is:

```
try {
  out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  try {
      ((DistributedFileSystem)fileSystem).recoverLease(new Path(path));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      //todo
    }
}
```